# Istio injected DB apps, make their service type as NodePort, the nodeport cannot be accessed

Tags: istio

I am using ***istio 1.0.2 version*** with **istio-demo-auth**.yaml, I have one **mssql** and **activemq** deployed in the same namespaces with other applications, both were be injected by istioctl. The applications can connect to those two services inside the cluster, but I make those two services' type as **NodePort**, it succeeded, but I cannot access those nodeport(52433, 51618, or 58161).

`kubectl get svc -n $namespace`
NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                          AGE
amq-master-01         NodePort    10.254.176.151           61618:51618/TCP,8161:58161/TCP   4h
mssql-master          NodePort    10.254.209.36            2433:52433/TCP                   33m

`kubectl get deployment -n $namespace`
NAME                  DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
activemq              1         1         1            1           4h
mssql-master          1         1         1            1           44m

Then I try to use gateway and virtualservice for using ingressgateway tcp port 31400. It works, as below:

```
    apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
    kind: Gateway
    metadata:
      name: tcp-gateway
      namespace: multitenancy
    spec:
      selector:
        istio: ingressgateway
      servers:
      - port:
          number: 31400
          name: tcp
          protocol: TCP
        hosts:
        - "*"
    ---
    apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
    kind: VirtualService
    metadata:
      name: mssql-tcp
      namespace: multitenancy
    spec:
      gateways:
      - tcp-gateway
      hosts:
      - "*"
      tcp:
      - match:
        - port: 31400
        route:
        - destination:
            host: mssql-master
            port:
              number: 2433
```

My question is,
1. How to configure for another http connection for 61618 or other tcp connections? Currently I can only use 31400 for one service(mssql-2433).
2. Why is that nodeport is not working after I inject those application into istio, how could it be work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the [documentation:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport)

### Type NodePort

If you set the  `type`  field to  `NodePort`, the Kubernetes master will allocate a port from a range specified by  `--service-node-port-range`  flag (default: 30000-32767), and each Node will proxy that port (the same port number on every Node) into your  `Service`. That port will be reported in your  `Service`’s  `.spec.ports[*].nodePort`  field.

Just update your config of all masters and you will be able to allocate any port.

Regarding to the second question:
I suggest you to create an issue on [github,](https://github.com/istio/istio.io/issues) because it looks like a bug, there are no restrictions to use nodePort in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Nick Rak, I don't quiet understand about your comment "Just update your config of all masters", can you give me a example, can I have more ports configured while using istio ingressgateway 31400 port?